# How to read array inside JSON Object this is inside another array

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am newbie to JSON, I am parsing a JSON Object and i was struck at a point where i have to read the array Elements inside a Object, that is again in another array..
 Here is MY JSON

```
   {
"DefinitionSource": "test",
"RelatedTopics": [
    {
        "Result": "",
        "Icon": {
            "URL": "https://duckduckgo.com/i/a5e4a93a.jpg"
        },
        "FirstURL": "xyz",
        "Text": "sample."
    },
    {
        "Result": "",
        "Icon": {
            "URL": "xyz"
        },
        "FirstURL": "xyz",
        "Text": "sample."
    },
    {
        "Topics": [
            {
                "Result": "",
                "Icon": {
                    "URL": "https://duckduckgo.com/i/10d02dbf.jpg"
                },
                "FirstURL": "https://duckduckgo.com/Snake_Indians",
                "Text": "sample"
            },
            {
                "Result": "sample",
                "Icon": {
                    "URL": "https://duckduckgo.com/i/1b0e4eb5.jpg"
                },
                "FirstURL": "www.google.com",
                "Text": "xyz."
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Here I need to read URL ,FIRSTURL and Text from RelatedTopics array and Topics array..
Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am able to read values inside RelateTopics[] array, But i am not getting How to read values inside Topics[] array

Comment: First test your json here http://jsonlint.org/ then post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
function (json) {
    json.RelatedTopics.forEach(function (element) {
        var url = element.Icon ? element.Icon.URL : 'no defined';
        var firstURL = element.FirstURL ? element.FirstURL : 'no defined';
        var text = element.Text ? element.Text : 'no defined';
        alert("URL: " + url + "\nFirstURL: " + firstURL + "\nText: " + text);

        if (element.Topics)
        {
            element.Topics.forEach(function (topicElement) { 
                alert("Topics - \n" + "URL: " + topicElement.Icon.URL + "\nFirstURL: " + topicElement.FirstURL + "\nText: " + topicElement.Text);
            }); 
        }
    });
};
```

---

[Look fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/foa5r6w6/)

Answer (score 0):

Loop through json Array like,

```
for(var i=0; i< RelatedTopics.length;i++){

     if($.isArray(RelatedTopics[i])){
       for(var j=0; j< RelatedTopics[i].Topics.length;j++){
        var topics=RelatedTopics[i].Topics[j];
        var text = topics.Text;
        var firsturl = topics.Firsturl;
        var url = topics.Icon.url;
       }

     }
}
```

if you want push it an array variable

Comment: I want to iterate Topics[] While iterating through RelatedTopics[].